# reduce bootstrap/primeng scss import footprint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, primeng

I have the following lines in an scss file:

```
  @include transition(all 0.5s ease);

  @include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
    width: 500px;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-only(xs) {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

these are requiring:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

and this brings the uncompressed payload up from a couple of kb to 324.57kb.

That's a bit much :) can anyone help me get just the parts that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first line is importing all of the bootstrap library.

Bootstrap is NOT listed as a dependency of [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup).

`media-breakpoint-only` comes from Bootstrap.

You can reduce this by changing the line:

`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

to something like (not tested):

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions'
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables'
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints'
```

This assumes that you are NOT using any other Bootstrap stuff in your code.

If you want only Media Query support use the smaller and excellent [sass-mq](https://github.com/sass-mq/sass-mq)

Comment: in total I only needed `@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_transition';`